# Scraping name list with varying numbers of last names

Tags: python

Trying to scrape swedish members of parliament with Beautiful Soup. When I run the scraper I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)".

The script outputs a csv, but only with five names. The sixth person on the list is named Alm Ericson, Janine (MP). I suppose the problem is that she has two last names - Alm Ericson, and the code only expects three values, firstname, lastname and party.

How should I code the field-split to make this work also for double last names?

The names on the page are written as

```
Last_name, first_name (party)
```

Code:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
import csv

source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-partier/").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

data = []

for span in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "fellow-name"}):
    cleanednames = span.text.strip()
    data.append(cleanednames)  #fields are appended to list rather printing

with open("riksdagsledamoter.csv", "w") as stream:
    fieldnames = ["Last_Name","First_Name","Party"]
    var = csv.DictWriter(stream, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    var.writeheader()
    for item in data:
        last_name, First_name, party = item.split()  #splitting data in 3 fields
        last_name = last_name.replace(",","")  #removing ',' from last name
        party = party.replace("(","").replace(")","")  #removing "()" from party
        var.writerow({"Last_Name": last_name,"First_Name": First_name, "Party": party})  #writing to csv row
```

Comment: Since it's not beautiful soup related, you should hcnage the tag and the question. There are a lot of noise in this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple regex that should do the trick

```
 import re
 print(re.match("(.*), (.*) \((.*)\)", 'Alm Ericson, Janine (MP)').groups())
```

Inspired from Corentin's answer

Comment: Aha, okey. I'm very new to Python and coding in general, could you show me where in the code I should put that?

Answer (score 4):

Well obviously splitting is not a good solution here. (or you should split on comma and parenthesis instead of spaces)

Using regexp :

```
import re
re.match('([^,]*), ([^(]*) \((.*)\)', 'Alm Ericson, Janine (MP)').groups()
```

Returns

```
('Alm Ericson', 'Janine', 'MP')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also use a function to return the parts in a list (not as clean as answer already give) e.g.

```
def getParts(inputString):
    list1 = inputString.split(",")
    list2 = list1[1].split("(")
    finalList = [list1[0], list2[0].strip(),list2[1].replace(")","")]
    return finalList

inputString = 'Alm Ericson, Janine (MP)'

print(getParts(s))
```

Comment: I think Corentin's answer is more appropriate for this case. It's more readable for other developpers and easier to maintain

Comment: I would agree @BlueSheepToken. I was just having a stab at writing some python. I'll happily take on board improvement notes. I already upvoted theirs.

Comment: It is just I prefer the regex approach since it is clearer, but your code is totally readable :) and more user friendly for new developers